# Открытие документов Word через Interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop

В общем, при открытии документа я заметил, что может происходить 2 проблемы:

1)Если документ кем-то открыт, то появится диалог, открыть ли документ в режиме ReadOnly.

2)Если документ поврежден, то не программа зависается, хотя на самом деле вылетает невидимый диалог "Документ при открытии кританул серьезной ошибкой, открыть?"

Как можно решить данные проблемы? В первой случае хочу, что бы диалога не было и он открывался в ReadOnly, а во втором повесить какой-нибудь TimeOut, что бы по его истечению переходить к открытию следующего документа, либо так же, что бы ответ был ДА.

Answer (score 1):

> В первом случае хочу, что бы диалога не было и он открывался в ReadOnly

У [`Documents.Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open.aspx) есть аргумент `ReadOnly` с помощью которого можно сразу открывать для чтения:

```
var document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(filename, ReadOnly:true);
```

> во втором повесить какой-нибудь TimeOut, что бы по его истечению переходить к открытию следующего документа, либо так же, что бы ответ был ДА.

Чтобы ответ был «да» можно попробовать отключить флагами все возможные подтверждения при открытии:

```
document = word.Documents.Open(PATH, 
                                ReadOnly:true, 
                                ConfirmConversions:false,
                                NoEncodingDialog:true);
```

Что касается таймаута, то не думаю, что Word Interop предусматривает такую возможность. Можно попробовать написать это средствами .Net. Например: выделить всю обработку файла в отдельный поток, затем по таймауту убивать поток и очищать все его ресурсы.

Comment: Получилось ли решить проблему с помощью таймера? Флагами при открытии документа проблема у меня не решается.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что помогу своим ответом.
Тем более, что из твоих тегов я знаю только слово Ворд и то - конвейера 2003 года :)

Я давно делал так, пытаясь изолироваться от всех этих внутренних механизмов Офиса, - **пытался открыть файл на запись**.
Если не получалось, то:
- откладывал до поры, или ...
- предпринимал действия, чтобы его закрыли, или ...
- **пытался открыть на чтение** - это должно всегда всегда получаться - и по ОК **копировал его в другое место**. Там с ним и работал. Потом возвращал, измененный, взад.

Есно, что "открыть на чтение-запись" - **не Вордом, а встроенными средствами VB(A)**.

В твоем случае (тем более,  что ты акцентируешься на *"Если документ поврежден"*) - сам бог велел работать с ним в песочнице. Да и поиметь походу резервную копия при этом на всякий пожарный...
.